# Trouble install CocoaPods

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

Whenever I try and gem install cocoapods I get an error

```
Basil-MBP:Magic8Ball Basil$ gem install cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-0.16.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.16.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.16.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for cocoapods-0.16.1...
ERROR:  While generating documentation for cocoapods-0.16.1
... MESSAGE:   "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
... RDOC args: --op /Users/Basil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails329/doc/cocoapods-0.16.1/rdoc lib --title cocoapods-0.16.1 Documentation --quiet
```

It works if I sudo gem install cocoapods but then "pods setup" doesn't work

Comment: what is the output of `pod setup?

Comment: In my case it says: "pod: Command not found."

Ah... because there was an error:
"Failed to build gem native extension."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the gem without the docs with `gem install cocoapods --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Comment: alright but do you have any idea why I might be getting the error message? I want to make sure this issue doesn't cause any other issues down the road

Comment: @BasilSiddiqui that's just the documentation, won't affect usage.

Answer (score 0):

**Try updating your gems also**

```
sudo update gems
```

**then**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```